# Suppose a subspace of $X$ is compact iff closed. Then is $X$ compact hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, separation-axioms

Let $X$ be a topological space.

1. If $X$ is compact then any closed subspace is compact.
2. If $X$ is hausdorff then any compact subspace is closed.

So if $X$ is compact hausdorff, then a subspace is closed if and only if it is compact. Does the converse hold?

If a subspace of a topological space $X$ is compact if and only if it is closed, then is $X$ hausdorff? (clearly it must be compact).

Note: this is not a duplicate of "If every compact set is closed, then is the space Hausdorff?", because $X$ must be compact here too.

Comment: I think the interval $[-1,1]$ with two origins could be a counterexample

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Is it?  Removing one of the origins yields a compact subset that isn't closed.

Comment: @slade you're right

Comment: One quick observation: $X$ must be $T_1$, as any singleton is compact and therefore closed.

Comment: @Slade what about a counterexample that is $T_0$ but not $T_1$? i.e. can we assume that $X$ must be $T_0$, and would that be enough?

Comment: I showed that $X$ is $T_1$ under your assumptions, so if we're looking for counterexamples we have to look for spaces that are $T_1$ but not Hausdorff.

Comment: @EricWofsey oh, I see. Sorry.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3211558/245577) seems to give a counterexample.

Comment: @EricWofsey Right, my bad. But the accepted answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530638/compactness-and-hausdorffness) gives again the counterexample mentioned above, and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/273087/are-there-non-hausdorff-examples-of-maximal-compact-topologies-in-the-lattice-of) seems to be related.